# How to jump to / call arbitrary memory in Rust

Tags: assembly, rust, x86, jit

I am experimenting with building a JIT that executes x86 instructions that the program produces. I think I have created a valid slice of x86 byte code that should print "Hello World", but I am not sure how to call it.

I am casting a pointer to the start of a vector to a void function and calling it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let msg: &[u8] = b"Hello World\0";

    let mut byte_codes: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1000);

    // Move width into edx
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xba, msg.len() as u8, 0, 0, 0]);
    
    // Msg to write
    byte_codes.push(0xb9);
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&(msg.as_ptr() as u64).to_be_bytes());
    
    // File descriptor and sys call
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xbb, 0x01, 0, 0, 0]);
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xb8, 0x04, 0, 0, 0]);
    
    // Sys call
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xcd, 0x80]);

    // Return
    byte_codes.push(0xc3); 

    let func_ptr = byte_codes.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        let func: fn() -> () = func_ptr.cast::<fn() -> ()>().read();
        func();
    }
}
```

Executing this returns:

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\run-bytecode.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
```

Removing all bytecode except the return call also leads to the same error.

I'm not sure what that error means. Is there a issue with the bytecode or is my function casting incorrect? How can I get it printing "Hello World"?

Comment: You may need to set the memory as executable before calling it. See the *mprotect* call here for Linux platform: https://github.com/jonathandturner/rustyjit/blob/master/src/main.rs

Comment: I expect the main issue is [W^X / DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX): in most modern system, a page can be *either* writable or executable. When you generate code you want to execute, you therefore need to change the protection mode of the page. Doing so is platform-specific.

Comment: An other issue you might have is ABI: you've asserted that the code you're calling is a Rust function. This means the Rust compiler will expect a Rust callable on the other side, and you've got no idea what that means because Rust has no stable ABI. So you need to craft your "function" such that it respects the "C" ABI, and you need to *tell* rustc that it's that by casting to an `extern fn`, and you may want to specify the ABI explicitely as e.g. the default `"C"` abi differs on Windows and Unices, as well as x86, x64, and ARM.

Comment: If you are using nightly, there are macros for both inline and global assembly. Also, on the ABI note, `extern "System"` might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a version that works:

```rust
use memmap::MmapMut;

fn main() {
    let msg: &[u8] = b"Hello World\0";

    let mut byte_codes: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1000);

    // Move width into edx
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xba, msg.len() as u8, 0, 0, 0]);

    // Msg to write
    byte_codes.push(0xb9);
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&(msg.as_ptr() as u32).to_le_bytes());

    // File descriptor and sys call
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xbb, 0x01, 0, 0, 0]);
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xb8, 0x04, 0, 0, 0]);

    // Sys call
    byte_codes.extend_from_slice(&[0xcd, 0x80]);

    // Return
    byte_codes.push(0xc3);

    let mut m = MmapMut::map_anon(byte_codes.len()).unwrap();
    m.clone_from_slice(&byte_codes);
    let m = m.make_exec().unwrap();
    let func_ptr = m.as_ptr();
    unsafe {
        let func: extern "C" fn() = std::mem::transmute(func_ptr);
        func();
    }
}
```

A couple of things needed to be fixed:

1. It looks like `byte_codes` is 32-bit x86 Linux code, so it will need to be run with something like `cargo run --target i686-unknown-linux-gnu`
2. Because it's 32-bit code, we want to cast `msg.as_ptr()` to `u32`.
3. x86 is little-endian so we want to use `.to_le_bytes()`
4. `func_ptr.cast::<fn() -> ()>().read()` doesn't cast to a function pointer, it casts the first 4/8 bytes of `byte_codes` to a function pointer.
5. Using `extern "C" fn()` makes sure Rust knows about the proper ABI
6. We use the memmap crate to create memory that we can mark as executable with `make_exec()`.

Comment: Another bug you didn't mention: EBX is call-preserved in the i386 System V ABI (like all other x86 and x86-64 calling conventions). But `0xbb, 0x01, 0, 0, 0` is `mov ebx, 1` (the first arg for the int 0x80 Linux 32-bit ABI), and I don't see this code saving/restoring EBX (e.g. on the stack).  If it was, there'd be a `pop ebx` between `int 0x80` and `C3 ret`.